# NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: "text"

Tags: formularios, flutter, textfield

Soy relativamente nueva en flutter, asi que seguramente este cometiendo un error.
Estoy tratando de hacer un formulario con `textField` quiero que al insertar texto en el campo de texto, lo que escribo me lo escriba abajo el programa.

**Intentos:**

- Añadi abajo el .dispose para que se elimine una evz ejecutado el código pero me sigue tirando el mismo error
- Intente inicializar la variable "myController" arriba, despues de crear el `StateFulWidget` pero vi que solo lo podia ponmer como una variable de tipo "final"asi que no podia y lo trate de remodificar asi

Adjunto mi código, aclarando que arriba de eso hay un `StateLessWidget` que tiene un `Column` y adentro de el ejecuto `InputConversor()`

```
class InputConversor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputConversorState createState() => _InputConversorState();
}

class _InputConversorState extends State<InputConversor> {
  //Creamos el conrtolador que sera utilizado apra reucperar el valor actual del TextFielc
  TextEditingController myController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    final myController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Limpia el controlador cuando el Widget se descarte
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        crearIngreso(),
        Text(myController.text),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget crearIngreso() {
    return TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.send,
      controller: myController,
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Captura de pantalla del error que me salta]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estás instanciando la variable global, fuera del método `initState` (estás creando una variable de método).

Cambia esto:

```dart
  TextEditingController myController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    final myController = TextEditingController();
  }
```

Por esto

```dart
  final myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: de nada, te invito a mi canal para que veas Flutter al siguiente nivel :) youtube.com/diegoveloper